# Handling Remote Data (Table Data - Undefined)

Tags: json, http, titanium-mobile

following the documentation  [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/guide/Handling_Remote_Data_with_HTTPClient_and_JSON)

I have my own web service with JSON data just for testing purposes [here](http://130.206.127.43:8080/Test)

Ti.API.info('Received text: ' + this.responseText); shows the JSON in console, but when i try display in table I get undefined?

The documentation example uses json.figters.length --- i used json.places.length, as it is the name on array list on my web application.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
var json, places, place, i, row, countryLabel, capitalLabel;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload : function(){


Ti.API.info('Received text: ' + this.responseText);

json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (i=0; i < json.places.length; i++)
{
    place = json.places[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: '60dp'
    });
    countryLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: place.country,
        font:{
            fontSize:'24dp'
    },
        height: 'auto',
        left: '10dp',
        top: '5dp',
        color: '#000',
        touchEnabled:false
    });
    capitalLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:'"' + place.captial + '"',
        font:{
            fontSize:'16dp'
        },
        height: 'auto',
        left: '15dp',
        top: '5dp',
        color: '#000',
        touchEnabled:false
    });

    row.add(countryLabel);
    row.add(capitalLabel);
    tableData.push(row);
}//end for

table.setData(tableData);
},

onerror: function() {
Ti.API.info('error, HTTP status = ' + this.status);
alert('Error Reading Data');
},
timeout:5000

});

xhr.open("GET", "http://130.206.127.43:8080/Test"); 
xhr.send();

win.add(table);
win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

you're pushing 2 labels into a row, but a row does not have a wrapper view.

Try something like this:

```
var rowView Ti.UI.createView({height: 60, layout: 'horizontal'});
rowView.add(countryLabel);
rowView.add(capitalLabel);

row.add(rowView);

tableData.push(row);
```